# Error when trying to clone repo from GitHub Desktop on SteamOS

Tags: github, steam

I'm having an issue with GitHub Desktop when trying to clone a repo on SteamOS.

It's a new Steam Deck. Fairly fresh out of the box. I installed GitHub Desktop from the Discover store.

- In GitHub Desktop, I click *Clone a repository from the internet*.
- It brings up a modal window entitled *Clone a repository*
- The modal has some options, I leave it set to the default of GitHub.com
- The button invites me to *Sign in*
- On clicking *Sign in* another modal invites me to sign in using my browser
- On clicking *Continue with browser* a new tab is opened in chrome (github.com/login/oauth/authorize...)
- Chrome invites me to open `xdg-open`
- When I do that I'm redirected back to GitHub Desktop.
- There's an error

  ```
  Can't find session /org/freedesktop/secrets/session/2
  ```

I've tried googling for an answer without success. How can I solve it?

Comment: No idea how to resolve, but have you tried using `git` in a terminal as a workaround?

Comment: I actually tried using the terminal first. I had issues setting up a credentials store, hence trying the app instead.